# To create registration form using C# and SQLite

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite

I would like to create  a  simple registration form for WINDOWS application.  I am using SQLite database which can be embedded into the project as I need to create a .exe file and mail it to my friend.

Now my registration form has 2 text boxes.

textBox1  for name

textBox2  for password

I need to insert these 2 values into the table and I have written the following code.

using Finisar.SQLite;

namespace Task_Sa

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    string connectionString;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connectionString = @"Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
           {

               SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();

               cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TaskTable(UserName,PassWord) values(@userName,@passWord)";
               cmd.Connection = sqlite_conn;
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@userName",textBox1.Text));  -> ERROR
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here I am getting the error as the parameters are not matching. 2 parameters  should be of type string and dbType.   Please help me to complete the code in this regard.  I have copied and pasted SQLite dll file in debug folder of my project and I also have used the  " **using Finisar.SQLite;** " name space.

Comment: I have an issue with the above code. I have 3 records in my table **TaskTable** that I created directly in the database using SQLIte manager.  Now when I run the project it deletes the previous table as I have given New=true in the connection string and creates new table altogether. If i give **new = false** in the connection string then i get access violation exception. How to insert new values through textbox UI, however retaining the previous value of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TaskTable(UserName,PassWord) values('"+  textBox1.Text +"','"+ textBox2.Text +"')";
```

Comment: pleae anwer my next question here.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982397/table-not-saved-in-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank space before `TaskTable` and `values`:

Your version:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TaskTable(UserName,PassWord) values(@userName,@passWord)";
```

Modified version:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO TaskTable (UserName,PassWord) values (@userName,@passWord)";
```

Comment: Here the problem is that the parameters are added without the quote (') surrounding them. Since the parameters are strings, they will be converted to a parameter with the SQL Server's type `varchar`, that requires something like 'username'.